# How to retrieve row value for coresponding table and column in t-sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working with a stored procedure that will search the whole database and return the table-name,column-name and value in ID field.I am comfortable with the searching with Table-name and column-name but not in getting the corresponding ID.

```
 table-name:Task_typen

 task_ID  task      name
  1       reading   read_task
  2       writing   write_task
  3       sleeping  sleep_task
```

example:when I search for a string 'writing'

Table-name i.e "Task_typen"   and
Column-name "task" 
are outputted,but i need the corresponding ID in task_ID for the string 'writing' i.e 2 should also be outputted along with table-name and column-name

stored procedure can be found below

```
CREATE TABLE myTable99 (TABLE_NAME sysname, COLUMN_NAME sysname, Occurs int)
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000),
 @TABLE_NAME sysname, 
 @COLUMN_NAME sysname,
 @Sargable varchar(80), 
 @Count int

SELECT @Sargable = 'PS'

DECLARE insaneCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns c INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables t
    ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE c.DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext')
   AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN insaneCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM insaneCursor INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO myTable99 (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Occurs) SELECT '
            + '''' +  @TABLE_NAME + '''' + ','
            + '''' + @COLUMN_NAME + '''' + ','
            + 'COUNT(*) FROM [' + @TABLE_NAME  
            + '] WHERE [' + @COLUMN_NAME + '] Like '
            + ''''+ '%' + @Sargable + '%' + ''''
    --SELECT @SQL
    EXEC(@SQL)
    IF @@ERROR <> 0 
    ------ <> means Not Equal To
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @SQL
            SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME
            GOTO Error
        END 
    FETCH NEXT FROM insaneCursor INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME
END

SELECT * FROM myTable99 WHERE Occurs <> 0 


Error:
CLOSE insaneCursor
DEALLOCATE insaneCursor

GO

DROP TABLE myTable99
GO

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: Are you from an Oracle background, converted to Sql Server?

Comment: No I am not from Oracle background,but I know(Very less)

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the output you'd like?

Comment: Can you please explain more? i didn't understand what is your problem.

Comment: I need to get the value in ID column for the particular string.. in query it can be queried as      SELECT task_ID FROM Task_typen WHERE task='writing'...this will output the task_ID as 2.   I need the same operation to be done in stored procedure,i.e it has to extract TAble-name containg 'writing' and then column-name in table and later the ID value i.e 2..

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cursors, something like this should work fine:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT '''+c.TABLE_NAME+''' AS [TAB], '''+c.COLUMN_NAME+''' AS [COL], COUNT(*) AS [COUNT] FROM '+c.TABLE_NAME+' WHERE '+c.COLUMN_NAME+' = '''+@SEARCHSTR+''' UNION ALL ' 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns c INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables t
    ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE c.DATA_TYPE IN ('char','varchar','text')
   AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT '''+c.TABLE_NAME+''' AS [TAB], '''+c.COLUMN_NAME+''' AS [COL], COUNT(*) AS [COUNT] FROM '+c.TABLE_NAME+' WHERE '+c.COLUMN_NAME+' = N'''+@SEARCHSTR+''' UNION ALL ' 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns c INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables t
    ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE c.DATA_TYPE IN ('nchar','nvarchar','ntext')
   AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

SELECT @SQL = SQL + 'SELECT ''END'' AS [TAB], ''END'' AS [COL], 0 AS [COUNT]'

EXEC(@SQL)
```